# Segregating Columns in Power BI using DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I want to make two new columns using DAX from existing columns.

- Column 1 is `Machine Status` having two values `PRODUCING` and `OFF`
- Column 2 is `Machine Name` having several machine names.

I want two separate columns of `Machines Producing` and `Machines OFF`.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and an example of your expected results please.

Comment: I assume you want the two new columns in separate tables?